verify fonction solution
how can i verify this solution Find all functions $f : ]-1, +\infty[ \rightarrow ]-1, +\infty[$ such that:

$$ f(x + f(y) + x f(y)) = y + f(x) + y f(x) \text{ for all } x, y \in ]-1, +\infty[; $$

$$ \frac{f(x)}{x} \text{ is strictly increasing on each of the intervals } ]-1, 0[ \text{ and } ]0, +\infty[. $$
so here is what i did
First, we set $ x = y = 0 $:
$$ f(f(0)) = f(0) $$
so $ f(0) $ is a fixed point.


Next, we set $ x = y $:
$$ f(x + f(x) + xf(x)) = x + f(x) + xf(x) $$
so $ x + f(x) + xf(x) $ is also a fixed point.
Now, let's check if there exists a fixed point in the given interval other than 0. Let $z$ be a fixed point in $ ]-1,0[ $ or $]0,+\infty[ $ such that $ f(z) = z $. Setting $z = y = x$ we have:
$$ f(z + f(z) + zf(z)) = z + f(z) + zf(z) $$
which gives:
$$ f(2z + z^2) = 2z + z^2 $$
so $ 2z + z^2 $ is also a fixed point.
If $z$ belongs to $] -1, 0 [$ then:
$ -1<z<0 $ and $ 2z+z^2= (z+1)^2-1$
$\implies$ : $2z+z^2$ $\in$ $]-1;0[$
and $2z+z^2<z$ in $]-1;0[$
Thus,
$$\frac{f(z)}{z} = \frac{f(2z + z^2)}{2z + z^2} = 1$$
is impossible since $f(x)$ is strictly increasing on $]-1;0[ $.
Similarly, in the interval $] 0, +\infty [$:
if $z \in ]0;+\infty[$
$$0<z$$ and $$0<2z+z^2$$
$\implies $ $2z+z^2 \in ]0;+\infty[$ implies $ 2z+z^2>z$ so
$$\frac{f(z)}{z} = \frac{f(2z + z^2)}{2z + z^2} = 1$$
is impossible because $f(x)$ is strictly increasing on $]0;+\infty[$.
The condition
$$\frac{f(z)}{z} = \frac{f(2z + z^2)}{2z + z^2} = 1$$
can only be true if and only if:
$$ 2z + z^2 = z $$
Hence, $ z(z + 1) = 0 $ which implies that $z= 0$ or $ z = -1$.
Since $z$ is a real number in $]-1;0[$ or $] 0; +\infty[ $, it follows that $z = 0$ is the only fixed point.
Thus,
$$ 0 = x + f(x) + xf(x) $$
which gives
$$ 0 = x + f(x)(1 + x) $$
so
$$ f(x) = \frac{-x}{x + 1} $$
